# How to don't overwrite Redux's state when dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux

so I'm trying to dispatch a few objects and then display them. The problem is instead of adding new object to array, I'm overwriting them and it changes to a new one.
So, I have a few products which are separate objects. I'm pushing them to an array and dispatching an array here:

```
function Product({ id, title, image, price, rating }) {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(
      pushItems({
        items,
      })
    );
    console.log(items);
  }, [items]);

  return (
    <div className="product">
      <div className="product__Info">
        <p>{title}</p>
        <p className="product__Info__price">
          <small>$</small>
          <strong>{price}</strong>
        </p>
        <div className="product__Info__rating">
          {Array(rating)
            .fill()
            .map((_, i) => (
              <p>⭐</p>
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src={image} alt="" />
      <button
        onClick={(e) =>
          setItems({
            title,
            image,
            price,
            rating,
          })
        }
      >
        Add to basket
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and that's how my reducer looks like, where I think the problem is:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const checkoutSlice = createSlice({
  name: "checkout",
  initialState: {
    items: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    pushItems: (state, action) => {
      state.items = [...state.items, action.payload.items];
    },
  },
});

export const { pushItems } = checkoutSlice.actions;
export const selectItems = (state) => state.checkout.items;

export default checkoutSlice.reducer;
```

I know how to do it in an "old way", but when I'm using slices I'm kinda confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Product component, doesn't need to store items array, you can directly update the items array in redux store

```
function Product({ id, title, image, price, rating }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onAddItem = (item) => {
      dispatch(pushItems({item}));
  }

  return (
    <div className="product">
      <div className="product__Info">
        <p>{title}</p>
        <p className="product__Info__price">
          <small>$</small>
          <strong>{price}</strong>
        </p>
        <div className="product__Info__rating">
          {Array(rating)
            .fill()
            .map((_, i) => (
              <p>⭐</p>
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src={image} alt="" />
      <button
        onClick={(e) =>
          onAddItem({
            title,
            image,
            price,
            rating,
          })
        }
      >
        Add to basket
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also note that state updation inside `redux-toolkit` slice doesn't need to take care of immutability as it internally used `immer`.

You can update your redux state like below:

```
const checkoutSlice = createSlice({
  name: "checkout",
  initialState: {
    items: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    pushItems: (state, action) => {
      state.items.push(action.payload.item);
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: I guess your way is similar to mine, so when I try to do this this way:
`pushItems: (state, action) => {
      state.items = action.payload.items;`, it overwrites my state.

Comment: push is different from replacing directly. As I mentioned, you need to use `state.items.push(action.payload.item)` Also note that I have changed the internal product code too

Comment: I tryed to do this like u said and I get `Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?`
When I try to `dispatch(pushItems({item)})` I get `Cannot read property 'push' of null`

Comment: This is basically correct but you forgot the action creator!  It should be dispatch(pushItems({item})).  Personally I would make the item be the entire payload rather than a property on the payload but that’s just a matter of opinion.

Comment: Oh and the initialState needs to have an array { items: [] } instead of { items: null } @larryfisherman that will fix your error

Comment: @LindaPaiste Thanks for pointing that out.  I updated my answer.